# Removing default shadow from search box

Tags: html, css

I created a search box:

```
<form>
   <input type="search" class="search" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

The search button seems to have some kind of default inner shadow which I'd like to remove. This is how my CSS looks:

```
form
{
    float: right;
}

.search
{
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 6px 14px 6px 30px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    background: url(../images/search.png) no-repeat 8px 6px;
}
```

The "box-shadow: none;" doesn't work, I also tried the "box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;" but that doesn't work either. How can I remove the shadow? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What type of box shadow? Do you mean the default orange color around the borders in Google Chrome?

Comment: I'm talking about this kind of shadow: [link](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~rselis/Capture.JPG). I'd like to achieve something "clean", like this for example: [link](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~rselis/Capture2.JPG)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Don't do this. The outline is good for accessibility.

Try `outline: 0`.  I think that you may also simply be referring to the default border.  Try updating the border to whatever is desirable such as `1px solid black`

http://jsfiddle.net/smZPy/